# what is "method" type in pandas, and how can I change it to List type?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe including list of tuples like `[(A,B),(c,F),(D,M),(N,P)]` (also the length of the list might change for each row) in one specific column.I used `cumsum` function to have the cumulative sum of the lists in a new column of the dataframe, but this function changed the type data in the new column from `list` to `method`. Does anyone know how I can return the type to `list`?

Comment: can you share some example code to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, you forget to add the `()` at the end of the `cumsum`. Here is an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 5, -1, 0])
>>> y = s.cumsum    #THE WRONG WAY
>>> type(y)
<class 'method'>
```

You should use `s.cumsum()` instead